# How to find out that user is no longer interacting with a page (not reload or exit)

Tags: javascript, browser

I'd like to track time when user is interacting with the page. As far as I understand user can basically leave a page by

1. Navigating away (back/forward)
2. Closing window
3. Opening new tab and just keeping the old tab in the background
4. Switch tabs/windows

While I understand I can use "onbeforeunload" for 1 and 2, what can I do about 3 and 4? From my experience it's pretty usual to see people with many tabs open all the time in Chrome/Edge but interacting only with one.
Is there any nice trick how to find out that user "deactivated" tab/window?

Comment: You could set up a `setInterval` that checks whether the window has focus or not

Comment: for number 3 this question could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087368/how-to-detect-if-user-it-trying-to-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab

Comment: thanks @user3299379, definitively useful when users navigates away by clicking on a link, but won't help when user just opens a new tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for the `blur` event.

```
  window.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
    //DO something   
  }, true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm, but with window.addEventListener(...). It doesn't work with document.addEventListener though. Tested on Chrome 56 & Edge. Can you please update the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You got it! Updated the answer :D