# window.locationbar.visible not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to identify popups where the location bar is not visible in selenium.

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String url = js.executeScript("return window.locationbar.visible;").toString();

The code above works in chrome . Is there a way to do something like this in IE?.I tried running the javascript in console but I do not get "locationbar" option there in IE.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by identify popups? What are you trying to do with the popups? What worked with Chrome? Show your code.

Comment: I want to use window.locationbar.visible to check if the location bar of a window is visible or not.I am using the code above.In chrome it return true when the location bar is visible and false otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Though the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793588(v=vs.85).aspx provides documentation on javascript read-only access to toolbar, a quick research around the internet suggests that IE does not provide access to toolbar and menu-bar.

Open the below link in IE to test http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/window-toolbar-example1.html. You will get an alert saying true in other browsers.

[image]

See the answer here [Internet Explorer 8 JS Error: 'window.toolbar.visible' is null or not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654297/internet-explorer-8-js-error-window-toolbar-visible-is-null-or-not-an-object)

Well, the good thing is that Microsoft edge now supports the property (Maybe this is the reason why the toolbar documentation reference is provided in MSDN page).

[image]